# Glide.with(this) ["this" underlined with red] "cannot resolve method"

Tags: android

I'm using paths as a string in my SQLite database, and I'm using Viewbinder to adopt views ..I'm trying to turn the paths in my SQLite database to pictures using Glide library..in Glide.with(this) "this" stays highlighted red ..what's wrong with my code?

EDIT 1
This my My code

MAINACTIVTY.JAVA

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    Database mDatabase;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] childFrom = new String[]{Database.DATABASE_CHILD_1,Database.DATABASE_CHILD_2,Database.DATABASE_CHILD_3};
        String[] groupFrom = new String[]{Database.DATABASE_GROUP_1};

        int[] groupTo = {R.id.group1};
        int[] childTo = {R.id.child1,R.id.child2,R.id.child3};

        simplecursortreeAdapter.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder());

        expandableListView = findViewById(R.id.expandableListview);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(simplecursortreeAdapter);
    }


    public class MyViewBinder implements SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.ViewBinder {

        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            int viewID = view.getId();
            switch(viewID){
                case R.id.group1 :
                    TextView groupName = (TextView) view;
                    String groupname;
                    groupname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_GROUP_1));
                    groupName.setText(groupname);
                    break;

                case R.id.child1 :
                    TextView friendName = (TextView) view;
                    String friend_name;
                    friend_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_CHILD_1));
                    friendName.setText(friend_name);
                    break;


                case R.id.child2 :
                    ImageView contactProfile = (ImageView) view;
                    byte[] imageBytes = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_CHILD_2));
                    if(imageBytes != null ){
                        // Pic image from database
                        contactProfile.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length));
                    }else {
                        // If image not found in database , assign a default image
                        contactProfile.setBackgroundResource(0);
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.child3 :
                    String urls;
                    urls = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_CHILD_3));
                    ImageView url=findViewById(R.id.child3);
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(urls).into(url);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
```

Comment: It ins't simple Glide.with(this)..... ? else you need to check gradle if you have the correct dependency

Comment: Yes i have the right version ..but i suspect the problem is with the code above  Glide app ..from String urls to ..

Comment: @Marcos you were right ..i did Glide..but "this" stays now highlited red..what seems to be the problem? with "cannot resolve method"

Comment: You need to pass a valid context, check answer to see how to get one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Glide.with(YourActivityName.this).load(urls).into(url);
```

Replace `YourActivityName` with your current activity.

Comment: @Mithum Thanks for the answer ..Now the build is successful but the app keeps stooping and i'm sure that the problem is with bloc in which glide is in(from case R.child3), because i just had add it ..before that the app would work fine..please verifi the bloc if there is something wrong with syntax

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ma.ac.iav.databasewithjava, PID: 3059
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in /data/app/ma.ac.iav.databasewithjava-sAa6lB92_LvNA62g3q3nZQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)

Answer (score 0):

It is simple Glide.with(this), you need to check gradle if you have the correct dependency.

The first parameter is a context,

If you you are in a enclosing class of a Context (an inner anonymous class such listeners) you need to reference the class outside that is a context so the statement would be:

```
Glide.with(OuterClassActivity.this).load(urls).into(url);
```

If you in a fragment you:

```
Glide.with(getActivity()).load(urls).into(url);
```

Or if you are on a helper method without contexts available:

```
ImageView url=findViewById(R.id.child3);
Glide.with(url.getContext()).load(urls).into(url);
```

Comment: i did add my java file in the post..could you show me exactly what to put? ..PS: i suspect there is something wrong with bloc from R.child3 in which glide is in ..because i did this(Glide.with(Mainactivity.this).load(urls).into(url); the build is succesful but the apps stops!

Comment: Oh.. you may be using a newer API than what the device you running into supports, for Font you must use FontCompat from support package

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: ma.ac.iav.databasewithjava, PID: 3059 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in /data/app/ma.ac.iav.databasewithjava-sAa6lB92_LvNA62g3q3nZQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)

Comment: you may be using a newer API than what the device you running into supports, for Font you must use FontCompat from support package... and you need to add full stack trace with line numbers and you will notice the one that throws it

Comment: This is the error..i always use API 26 in my projects ..and for the device i use one with API 26

Comment: Don't ignore red highlights for NewerAPI and also dont add @Suppress("NewerApi")

Comment: before adding the bloc (in which glide is in) , the app was working fine ..but when i added the bloc the apps stops now ..so i don't think there is a problem with API

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't understa,d what do you mean by "Don't ignore red highlights for NewerAPI and also dont add @Suppress("NewerApi")

Comment: Just checking if you had newerapis problems.. but you need fulll stacktrace with line numbers and check the exactly one that throws your error